# tfs loses workspace mapping. No workspace matching * found on this computer

Tags: tfs

Since this morning I have been having trouble with my TFS. It actually forgets the workspace mapping and doesn't recognize that the solution has been added to source control. There is an option to actually add the selected projects to source control.

I don't want to edit workspace and make it download all files again.
I tried using the tfs command prompt

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>tf workspaces /computer:LAP14643 /owner:* /server:cs\Development
No workspace matching *;* on computer LAP14643 found in Team Foundation Server cardontfs\Development.

tf workspaces
No workspace matching * found on this computer
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run tf.exe from a mapped folder.

I would have thought that "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC" is not mapped folder.

Comment: As a way to make your answer more helpful: What would you do if you have a mapped folder (or at least a folder where you've pulled source), but it's not mapped?

Comment: Hello, I run into this problem today when our computer name have to change for company policy. What is a mapped folder? Do you mean we should go to all project that we map to TFS and then run the command in all of them to change username or computer name?

Comment: Hey Pham, A mapped folder is where you have a workspace created to. 
What kind of workspaces have you got? Server or Local?